# Sinatra app with multiple controllers: how do I tell rspec what the routes are?

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra

I'm working on an existing sinatra app that spans a number of controllers. These are currently routed in the config.ru file like so:

```
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require(:default)
=begin
# The gem file includes these:
gem 'rack'              ,    '1.5.2', :groups => [:default, :test]
gem 'rack-accept'       ,    '0.4.5'
gem 'rack-mount'        ,    '0.8.3'
gem 'rack-protection'   ,    '1.5.1'
gem 'rack-test'         ,    '0.6.2', :groups => [:test]
=end
use Rack::ContentType

maps = {
  '/'                  => RootController,
  '/users'             => UsersController,
  '/animals'           => AnimalsController,
}
maps.each do |path, controller|
  map(path){ run controller}
end
```

This file is launched via config.ru (under Thin). But test files don't run under rackup (or Thin).
How do I load the controllers under rspec?

The problem is that when I put a 'get "/PATH"' or 'post' in my tests, Ruby complains about an
argument mismatch (2 for 0).  If the 'get' has no argument, Ruby gives a different argument
mismatch (0 for 1).  They're both sort of wrong -- get takes a path, an optional hash, and an optional block.
So something is clearly not wired up correctly.

Some of the code is here:

config.ru: http://pastie.org/8673836
spec_helper.rb at http://pastie.org/8673835
Error message at http://pastie.org/8673793
Simple controller at http://pastie.org/8673785

The names are slightly different in the pasties, but the gist is the same.
How do you wire up the controllers when you don't have the environment
config.ru gives you?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you include the main parts of your pastie.org things, please?

Comment: A teammate figured out the problem -- it was in a third-party library we're using.  I'm on something else, and it'll be too much trouble to post a cleaned-up main routine, plus its dependencies.  Thanks for asking, though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is somewhere in the code base, but rack doesn't make it easy to determine where.

I filed a bug on this at
https://github.com/rack/rack/issues/652

Comment: And I closed the bug.  The problem was in a library the code uses.